# How to create an online shopping cart in php

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

I am creating a shopping cart which has four buttons continue shopping, clear cart, update cart and place order I am facing a problem with the sessions like when I  press the clear cart button it shows the

```
 undefined index cart
```

but the cart comes from the session and when i press the clear cart button

```
it unsets the session of cart
```

so where i am doing it wrong ? can anyone help ?
here is my code

```
<?php
    include("includes/db.php");
    include("includes/functions.php");

    if($_REQUEST['command']=='delete' && $_REQUEST['pid']>0){
        remove_product($_REQUEST['pid']);
    }
    else if($_REQUEST['command']=='clear'){
        unset($_SESSION['cart']);
    }
    else if($_REQUEST['command']=='update'){
        $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
            $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
            $q=intval($_REQUEST['product'.$pid]);
            if($q>0 && $q<=999){
                $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty']=$q;

            }
            else{
                $msg='Some proudcts not updated!, quantity must be a number between 1 and 999';
            }
        }
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Shopping Cart</title>
<script language="javascript">
    function del(pid){
        if(confirm('Do you really mean to delete this item')){
            document.form1.pid.value=pid;
            document.form1.command.value='delete';
            document.form1.submit();
        }
    }
    function clear_cart(){
        if(confirm('This will empty your shopping cart, continue?')){
            document.form1.command.value='clear';
            document.form1.submit();
        }
    }
    function update_cart(){
        document.form1.command.value='update';
        document.form1.submit();
    }


</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="form1" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="pid" />
<input type="hidden" name="command" />
    <div style="margin:0px auto; width:600px;" >
    <div style="padding-bottom:10px">
        <h1 align="center">Your Shopping Cart</h1>
    <input type="button" value="Continue Shopping" onclick="window.location='products.php'" />
    </div>
        <div style="color:#F00"><?php echo'' ;?></div>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="1px" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:11px; background-color:#E1E1E1" width="100%">
        <?php
            if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
                echo '<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-weight:bold"><td>Serial</td><td>Name</td><td>Price</td><td>Qty</td><td>Amount</td><td>Options</td></tr>';
                $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
                for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
                    $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
                    $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
                    $pname=get_product_name($pid);
                    if($q==0) continue;
            ?>
                    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td><?php echo $i+1?></td><td><?php echo $pname?></td>
                    <td>$ <?php echo get_price($pid)?></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product<?php echo $pid?>" value="<?php echo $q?>" maxlength="3" size="2" /></td>                    
                    <td>$ <?php echo get_price($pid)*$q?></td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:del(<?php echo $pid?>)">Remove</a></td></tr>
            <?php                   
                }
            ?>
                <tr><td><b>Order Total: $<?php echo get_order_total()?></b></td><td colspan="5" align="right"><input type="button" value="Clear Cart" onclick="clear_cart()"><input type="button" value="Update Cart" onclick="update_cart()"><input type="button" value="Place Order" onclick="window.location='billing.php'"></td></tr>
            <?php
            }
            else{
                echo "<tr bgColor='#FFFFFF'><td>There are no items in your shopping cart!</td>";
            }
        ?>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't already started populating your cart then the element will be undefined. When dealing with array elements it's always better to add the additional test array_key_exists(). However in your case the problem is more about the way you handle your array generally.

PHP is quite forgiving, so you have to enforce your own disciplines on the way you code. One piece of very good practice which is worth getting used is to explicitly initialise your variables before you start using them.

```
// somewhere near the top of your code
$_SESSION['cart'] = array_key_exists('cart', $_SESSION)?$_SESSION['cart']:array();
```

and don't unset it in the clear test ... just set it back to an empty array.

```
else if($_REQUEST['command']=='clear'){
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}
```

Comment: thanks sir that code worked fine but now my update cart is not working

Comment: If this worked, please chcek it as an answer to your original question. You're not supposed to extend questions by adding more issues afterwards. Questions are supposed to be one-shot question-answer sets. However, since you're new, please post your error message as a reply comment and I'll see what I can do ... Also explain if the error occurs on the first attempt after a clear or on every attempt new, cleared or in progress. Always provide the program feedback and the use case it maeks life a lot easier.

Comment: answer to your second question ... It fails if the cart is empty because `$max=count($_SESSION["cart"]); for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){` will fail if $max == 0 because it doesn't satisfy the condition `$i<$max if $i == 0`

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your request handler where you actually inert anything into the cart ... all update seems o do is to update the number requested of a particular product. If you intend to use update to add items as well as change their quantities, you need to rethink that whole section, and correcting that is outside the scope of this single question. I suggest you raise another question rather than stretching this one.

Comment: i am just allowing the user to change the quantity of the product

Comment: Then how do you originally populate your cart ?? You can't just update the quantity of an item you don't already have in the array :) ... In fact there are a few places where this update code and the design of the cart need fixing to make it easier to maintain and understand. If you are just starting up with PHP this is a good learning exercise, but I think the answer will run on way beyond a simple 'here's how you fix it'

Comment: Take a good look at associative arrays in PHP and work out how to set up $_SESSION['cart'] to use the product ID as the array key instead of $i ... like `$_SESSION['cart']['productID'][qty']` then you can do away with the iterative loop altogether and simplify your code tremendously... As I said - Open a new question please

Answer (score 0):

here is *Simple PHP Shopping Cart Tutorial*

```
$product_id = $_GET['id']; //the product id from the URL 
$action = $_GET['action']; //the action from the URL 

//if there is an product_id and that product_id doesn't exist display an error message
if($product_id && !productExists($product_id)) {
    die("Error. Product Doesn't Exist");
}

switch($action) { //decide what to do 

    case "add":
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++; //add one to the quantity of the product with id $product_id 
    break;

    case "remove":
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]--; //remove one from the quantity of the product with id $product_id 
        if($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] == 0) unset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]); //if the quantity is zero, remove it completely (using the 'unset' function) - otherwise is will show zero, then -1, -2 etc when the user keeps removing items. 
    break;

    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION['cart']); //unset the whole cart, i.e. empty the cart. 
    break;

}

?>
```

from [here](http://jameshamilton.eu/content/simple-php-shopping-cart-tutorial)

Comment: please print_r($_SESSION); on top of the page, check each time,ins upd del . is it works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
switch($action) { //decide what to do 

    case "add":
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++; //add one to the quantity of the product with id $product_id 
    break;

    case "remove":
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]--; //remove one from the quantity of the product with id $product_id 
        if($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] == 0) unset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]); //if the quantity is zero, remove it completely (using the 'unset' function) - otherwise is will show zero, then -1, -2 etc when the user keeps removing items. 
    break;

    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION['cart']); //unset the whole cart, i.e. empty the cart. 
    break;
```