# creating a shopping cart and updating the values in it using php

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I am creating a shopping cart which has four buttons continue shopping, clear cart, update cart and place order I am facing a problem with the sessions like when I press the update cart button it empties my cart rater then updating it any one help in showing me that where i am doing it rong
here is my code

```
<?php
    include("includes/db.php");
    include("includes/functions.php");

    if(isset($_REQUEST['command'])=='delete' && $_REQUEST['pid']>0){
        remove_product($_REQUEST['pid']);
    }
    elseif(isset($_REQUEST['command'])=='clear'){
        $_SESSION["cart"] = array();
    }
    elseif($_REQUEST['command']=='update'){
        $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
            $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
            $q=intval($_REQUEST['product'.$pid]);
            if($q>0 && $q<=999){
                $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty']=$q;

            }
            else{
                $msg='Some proudcts not updated!, quantity must be a number between 1 and 999';
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

here is my javascript

```
function update_cart(){
    document.form1.command.value='update';
    document.form1.submit();
}
```

here is my code

```
<?php
            if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
                echo '<tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-weight:bold"><td>Serial</td><td>Name</td><td>Price</td><td>Qty</td><td>Amount</td><td>Options</td></tr>';
                $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
                for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
                    $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
                    $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
                    $pname=get_product_name($pid);
                    if($q==0) continue;
            ?>
                    <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><td><?php echo $i+1?></td><td><?php echo $pname?></td>
                    <td>$ <?php echo get_price($pid)?></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="product<?php echo $pid?>" value="<?php echo $q?>" maxlength="3" size="2" /></td>                    
                    <td>$ <?php echo get_price($pid)*$q?></td>
                    <td><a href="javascript:del(<?php echo $pid?>)">Remove</a></td></tr>
            <?php                   
                }
            ?>
                <tr><td><b>Order Total: $<?php echo get_order_total()?></b></td><td colspan="5" align="right"><input type="button" value="Clear Cart" onclick="clear_cart()"><input type="button" value="Update Cart" onclick="update_cart()"><input type="button" value="Place Order" onclick="window.location='billing.php'"></td></tr>
            <?php
            }
            else{
                echo "<tr bgColor='#FFFFFF'><td>There are no items in your shopping cart!</td>";
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Asking Question 2nd time ?

Comment: yeah now the update button is not working sir

Comment: Asking a different question Bhavin. The first one was about the clear option. I advised him to open another question about the update one because it was an exetnsion of the original one and the resolution was different.

Comment: yes sir so what is the solution for the update query

Comment: and asking the question with a fundamentally different script that the one asked 10 minutes previously. It nether implemented the solution to the previous question, nor is the code the same as the code posted previously.

Answer (score 1):

`isset($_REQUEST['command'])` yield either `true` or `false`. Comparing that value to `'delete'` yields the same value as `isset($_REQUEST['command'])`, because `'delete'` is cast to boolean `true` for comparison with another boolean.

Especially, the result of

```
isset($_REQUEST['command'])=='clear'
```

is *always* the same as

```
isset($_REQUEST['command'])=='update'
```

so if the condition of the second `elseif` holds, so does the condition of the first `elseif`. The body of the second `elseif` is therefore never executed (the body of the first `elseif` is executed instead).

Comment: Very true and in the case published, nothing but the delete option would ever be invoked. The OP posted another question recently ... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584300/how-to-create-an-online-shopping-cart-in-php/15584517?noredirect=1#comment22096012_15584517 ... and I made the erroneous assumption that I was dealing with the same code he posted 10 minutes previously in that one. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: The delete option is skipped if `$_REQUEST['pid'] <= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Several points. Firstly, I see nowhere in the code where you acually add any products to your session array. This means that you'll never have any products to update.Also the for loop

```
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
```

will never start because in the initial condition $max is set to 0 and the bounding condition of the loop is $max < 0 i.e. 0<0 ..

Your initial premise is fundamentally wrong if you are trying to update just the quantities, because the session cart will never have any products to update, and from the solution to the first question you raised, the setting of $_SESSION['cart'] to array() would always guarantee an empty _SESSION cart.

These lines:

```
elseif(isset($_REQUEST['command'])=='clear'){
    unset($_SESSION['cart']);
}
```

Will fail with an undefined error on the unset() line if the cart is initially undefined. See the answer to your first question for elaboration of that.

In your page display code at the top you have

```
        if(is_array($_SESSION['cart'])){
```

If you implemented the solution to the 'clear' question, this will always return true since you initialise the cart to an empty array. (BTW - please update the code above to reflect the 'clear' solution from that question)

As for the rest of the update code, I could suggest several improvements, but unless you can implement a method of populating your cart, then it's all a bit academic.

If, on the other hand, this is omly one from a set of scripts, and if it expects the cart to have been populated by another one before it does anything, then you will need to explicity add a test to make sure $max is not zero and do nothing if it is.

```
    $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
    if ($max > 0) {
      for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
        $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
        $q=intval($_REQUEST['product'.$pid]);
        if($q>0 && $q<=999){
          $_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty']=$q;
        } else {
           $msg='Some proudcts not updated!, quantity must be a number between 1 and 999';
        }
      }
    } else {
      // handle the error your way
    }
```

Comment: See [Loose comparison with ==](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose) for what happens when you compare a boolean and a string in PHP.

Comment: Sorry Oswald .. I skipped that one :) ... the fact that isset() as used at all was the error. but certainly if isset() returns a TRUE and I compare it to 'string' using == it will return a TRUE value for the condition, but not if I use === ... my bad.